# Two correct choices in exam class with different format

Tags: exam

I'm trying to define a new correct choice command with a different format than the included `\CorrectChoice` in the `exam` class, without affecting that command. For example, I want the correct answers to show in red and partial credit answers to show in blue. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\PartialCorrectChoice}[1]{
    \ifprintanswers
\CorrectChoice \textcolor{blue}{#1}
\else
\CorrectChoice #1
\fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
First question.
    \begin{choices}
    \choice Wrong
    \CorrectChoice Right
    \PartialCorrectChoice{Points for trying}
    \end{choices}
\question
Second question.
\begin{choices}
    \choice Wrong
    \CorrectChoice Right
    \choice No partial credit here
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

And I get:

[image]

Which isn't exactly pretty, I'm not sure how to get the letter of the option to be also blue. I tried using `\CorrectChoiceEmph` inside of `\ifprintanswers`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe not a good solution... but removing the color ink from your printer? :)